# Converting from java to c#

Tags: c#, java

I need your help. I am converting from java to c# and I have run into a roadblock.
I am looking for a c# equivalent of the java Enumeration class. I have gone through the C# Enumeration documentation and I wasn't able to find something that mirror the java version, especially when it came to too methods that I need and these are the Enumeration. hasMoreElements() and the Enumeration.nextElement().

```
protected boolean populateResultSetDataToRRX(Hashtable objStructureHT,String strObjectName  ,String strMultiUserCheck)
{
    try{
        Enumeration objEnum = null;
        for (objEnum=objStructureHT.keys(); objEnum.hasMoreElements();){
            String strFieldName = (String)objEnum.nextElement();
            String strBindFieldName=extractBindField(strFieldName).toUpperCase();
            String strDataType = (String)objStructureHT.get(strFieldName);
            String strFieldValue="";
            if(strDataType.equals("date")){
                if(objResultSet.getTimestamp(strBindFieldName)==null)
                    strFieldValue="";
                else
                    strFieldValue = objResultSet.getTimestamp(strBindFieldName).toString();
            }else {
                strFieldValue = objResultSet.getString(strBindFieldName);
            }
            if(!populateRRXField(strObjectName,strFieldName,strFieldValue,strDataType)){
                return false;
            }
        }// end of for objEnum hasNoMoreElements
        if (strMultiUserCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("Token")) {
            objRRX.addField(strObjectName,"Token",
                objResultSet.getString("Token"));
        }
        objRRX.addField(strObjectName,"selected","N");
        objRRX.assignErrorStatus(strObjectName, strStatus, "SUCCESS");
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in populateResultSetDataToRRX " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}// end of function populateResultSetDataToRRX
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a specific scenario where you need this?

Comment: I don't know what the enumeration class does in java, but I guess you're looking for an `IEnumerable<T>`? Post the specific code and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: He's probably refering to this `Enumeration<E>` interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html (I had to look it up as well, never used it before).

Comment: You can not. C# and Java is not same

Comment: @barwnikk `you can not` - Can you explain why? what is your statement based on?

Comment: Looks to me like some kind of (horrible) reflection stuff used to get property values out of objects in a dictionary. Unless I'm really drunk? It would be helpful if you added a sample of what your inputs are and what outputs do you expect. Really, really C# code is not like this, and you don't (normally) deal with reflection in C# for regular daily operations.

Comment: 6 downvotes?? You're a harsh lot...

Comment: @HighCore: You must be drunk. ;-) There is no reflection happening here. Perhaps you and I don't write C# code like this, but I guarantee you it's out there. It's just as easy to write bad code in C# as in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods on [`Enumeration<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) look like they achieve similar purposes to the [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) interface in C#, but with slightly different semantics. The [`MoveNext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) method, for example, fulfills both purposes: it moves to the next element *and* returns a boolean to tell you whether there was a next element to move to.

But I find it highly unlikely that you really *need* this interface. Can you share more details about what you're trying to achieve? It's often possible to write much nicer C# code than you'd get doing a straight-across conversion.

#### Update

Ack! My eyes! Okay, so this is antiquated (or just poorly done) Java code in the first place. Instead of:

```
    Enumeration objEnum = null;
    for (objEnum=objStructureHT.keys(); objEnum.hasMoreElements();){
        String strFieldName = (String)objEnum.nextElement();
```

It should be:

```
    for (String strFieldName : objStructureHT.keys()){
```

Which translates nicely in C# to (assuming you're using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for `objStructureHT`:

```
    foreach (string strFieldName in objStructureHT.Keys){
```

However, the only reason you're even getting the `Keys` is so that you can look up each one and get its value too, right? So there's a better way:

```
    foreach (var pair in objStructureHT){
        string strFieldName = pair.Key;
        string strDataType = pair.Value;
        ...
```

... which makes one wonder why we're even using a `Dictionary` instead of a class with `FieldName` and `DataType` properties. But that's getting beyond the scope of this question.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: @chinonsoakolam click on "Edit" in your question and copy paste the code and click "Save Edits".

Comment: BLess you, Bless you, Bless you

Comment: Just to be sure, I should skip the hastable, and use a Dictionary in its place right?

Comment: @ChinonsoAkolam: Yes. Just as `Hashtable` in Java is deprecated (you should be using `HashMap<,>` instead), `Hashtable` in C# is antiquated (use `Dictionary<,>` instead).

Comment: Thank you. Pls sorry for the inconvenience, can I ask another question. So looking at that function, they use a ResultSet object called objResultSet, and also one of the methods of the ResultSet class getTimestamp. I check c# alternatives and I found DataSet,Datareader and Recordset, but none of them had anything that mirrored the getTimestamp function. Do you know how I can mirror this?. thank you.

Comment: @ChinonsoAkolam: Typically if you have a different question you should ask it as a separate question on StackOverflow, so the whole community can pitch in, and the pages stay more relevant for when other people are trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), *Enumeration* is kind of deprecated and the new *Iterator* interface should be used in Java. In C#, on the other hand, an interface called *IEnumerator* was in use since the first version. Later, generic *IEnumerator<T>* was introduced. All of these interfaces' role is to implement the [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).

In contrast to the Java version, C# does not have separate *hasMoreElements()* and *nextElement()* methods. Both of them are unified into the *MoveNext()* method which returns *true* on successful iteration step and *false* once there are no more elements to iterate on. Since version 2.0 of the C# language there is the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword, which instructs compiler to generate a proper implementation of the interface and is very usable for the simple cases.

*IEnumerator* is usually being used in conjunction with the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface and the [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) keyword.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx).

**Update**
OK, the answer by StriplingWarrior ends the discussion.

Comment: +1 for going to the effort to investigate and explain this, anyway. :-)